# Classifying PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I came across the following PDE while reading a book:
$$
u_t + (au)_x + \frac1{2}(b^2u^2)_x + \frac1{2}(b^2u_x)_x=0
,
$$
where $b$ and $a$ are smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into itself.  It seems that this PDE's solutions exist under some assumptions, but what type of PDE is it?

---

**What I did:**

I did a bit of fiddling and got it down to
$$
\frac1{2}(ub^2+1)u_{xx} + (a + 2bb_x)u_x + (a_x+2bb_x)u^2 + u_t=0.
$$
It looks like it is *parabolic* but the presence of $u$ in the $u_xx$'s coefficient makes me feel that that is wrong.

Comment: Your equation in the 'what I did' section is wrong. At the least the coefficient of $u_{xx} $ should be $b^2/2$, other terms may be wrong also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a second order quasilinear homogeneous PDE. For a quasilinear equation (one where the terms involving the highest order derivative are linear in the unknown function) you can classify using the standard linear approach, as such so long as $b \neq 0$ the equation is *parabolic*. If at any point $b=0$ then you will nead to be careful.

Comment: Perfect, in the case I care most about b is bounded away from $0$.  Just for learning's sake, where should I look if I want to learn more about the case where $b$ can vanish?

Comment: At any points where $b=0$ the last two terms dissappear and the equation becomes hyperbolic. Dealing with such a change is, in general, hard. If you're sufficiently interested then you want to look up 'singular PDEs'

Comment: Cool, I'll do that.  Thanks a lot Eddy

Comment: @Eddy why are you deeming this PDE inhomogeneous? I don't see any summand depending soley on $x$ or $t$. Also why can you just apply the classification for linear PDE to this quasi-linear one, because what happens when the solution changes sign? i.e. how would you classify: $u_{tt} - u\Delta u = 0$? it depends on the solution if this is elliptic or hyperbolic...

Comment: Homogeneity corrected

Comment: You can't apply the  linear classification to the PDE you stated because that is not quasilinear. However, you could apply to $u_{tt} - u_{xx} =u^2$ because it is quasilinear, and its the terms involving the highest order derivatives that determines the behavior of the system. See any text on PDEs for explanation of the classification derivation and meaning.

Comment: Of course $u_{tt} - u\Delta u = 0$ is quasi-linear! The equation is linear in $u_{tt}$ and $u_{x_i x_i}$ which makes it quasi-linear. The equation you gave ($u_{tt} - u_{xx} = u^2$) is better classified as semi-linear.

Comment: Your right, I tried to edit my comment as soon as I posted it but ut wouldn't let me. This what it should have said.

Comment: The quasilinear classification system of an order $n$ PDE can produce a classification that is dependent on the unknown function and derivatives up to order $n-1$. It is not always that useful, but that's how it works. The restriction to linear equations results in a classification that varies with location, and with constant coefficients you get a universal classification. To understand classification better see any PDE textbook.

Comment: I have looked in Evans' PDE book (which is of course a standard and well known reference) and he also only defines the classification of second-order PDEs for *linear* ones. Please direct me to a PDE textbook where the classification for quasi-linear PDEs is explained.

Comment: I can't remember where I read about quasilinear classification, but I'm surprised it's not in Evans. I think the book by Garabedian explains classification well, but I don't have it to hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your PDE is *nonlinear*. The classification you are aiming for is (usually) only applied to *linear* PDE (often only even with constant coefficients, but one can extend to variable coefficients easily). That's why you can't classify this PDE.

The linear part of this PDE is $u_t + a_x u_x + \frac{1}{2}bb_x u_x + \frac{1}{2} b^2 u_xx = 0$. That is parabolic if $b$ is not zero.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to solve this thing, or where to look if the solution exists?